# Como capturar datos de una checkbox en laravel 7

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, array

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en laravel 7 donde tengo una seccion de cotizacion de productos, esta parte la divido en 5 categorias que estan dentro de un elemento html acordeon que esta alimentado por la base de datos

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{route('factura')}}">
  @csrf
  <div class="accordion accordion-block">
    <div class="accord-btn" id="pfl">
      <h4>PROGRAMA DE FORMACION LABORAL</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="accord-content">
      <strong>PROGRAMA DE FORMACION LABORAL</strong>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-primary">
          <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE</td>
            <td>PRECIO</td>
            <td>SELECCIONE</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($data as $dat) @if($dat->categoria == 'pfl')
        <tr>
          <td><a href="{{ route('cursos.ofert', $dat) }}"><small class="text-uppercase">{!!$dat->titulo1!!}</small></a></td>
          <td><small>{{number_format($dat->precio, 2)}}</small></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" tu-attr-precio="{{ $dat->precio }}" class="mis-checkboxes" name="total[]" value="{{$dat->id}}"></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="nombre_curso[]" value="{!!$dat->titulo1!!}">
        </tr>
        @endif @endforeach
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
      <td><input name="total" id="total" type="text" placeholder="0.00" /></td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between text-center"><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" target="_blank" type="submit" id="total">Generar Ticket</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

luego en un script realizo la sumatoria de los precios totales`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click keyup', '.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales', function() {
    calcular();
  });

});

function calcular() {
  var tot = $('#total');

  tot.val(0);
  $('.mis-checkboxes,.mis-adicionales').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('mis-checkboxes')) {
      tot.val(($(this).is(':checked') ? parseFloat($(this).attr('tu-attr-precio')) : 0) + parseFloat(tot.val()));
    } else {
      tot.val(parseFloat(tot.val()) + (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val())));
    }
  });
  var totalParts = parseFloat(tot.val()).toFixed(2).split('.');
  tot.val('$' + totalParts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + (totalParts.length > 1 ? totalParts[1] : '00'));
} <
/script>
```

lo que quiero es que esto se envie a un pdf pero que no se guarde en una base de datos ya que es informacion de cotizacion y para recolectar los datos del cliente tengo un formulario de contacto. les agradezco de antemano su ayuda

Comment: Hey andres, que tal? A ver si entendí: este código te funciona y lo que deseas es tomar la página que te muestra tu navegador y convertir eso en pdf?

Comment: bueno lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario le de check en box esa informacion se lleve al controlador y luego se genere el pdf. actualmente logro llevar la informacion pero solo me esta trayendo un solo curso si selecciono varios solo me trae el primer curso

Comment: Según el marcado html que usas no deberías tener problemas recuperando los ids desde el controlador de laravel. Podrías compartir el código que usas en el controlador?